# Printing Object properties in UI

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to print the distinct values from the "crop" column of a shape file. I am able to print "crop wise count of unique points" in the console.

[image: Crop wise unique points print results in console]

This may be naive but I m wandering how to print it in the UI, same as it is printing in console.

I am trying `.evaluate()` but I am not getting results.

[Link to my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/72429a0d6b3dda415df1f2586033a010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will answer **just** what you've asked:

you can use the (client-side) `JSON.stringify()` function: `JSON.stringify(val)` in your case.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c2b0bc0d521ae7940f0f8966e9f4e884

You can ask in another question how to make the output a multiline string

Comment: Thanks for help @Rodrigo. I have already asked that " printed text should be exactly as  it is printed in console". `+JSON.stringify(val, null, '\t')` worked for me to print multi-line text. where `val` is a JSON object.